# Python: Plot a graph with the same x-axis values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say that I have two lists:

```
yvalues = [30, 40, -20, 0, -10, 20, 45, 12, -5, ....]
Dates = ['20110103', '20110103', '20110103', '20110108', '20110108', '20110108', '20110113', '20110113', '20110113', ....]
```

The first entry in `Dates` does correspond to the first value in `yvalues` and so on. The dates repeat themselves because I observe multiple `yvalues` every 5 days.

Now if I want to plot the `yvalues` with `Dates` as x-axis, I do:

```
plt.plot(yvalues) 
plt.xticks(dates)
```

It gives me an error. If I try: `plt.plot(Dates, yvalues)`, I get this nasty graph:
[image]

How can I plot on the x-axis the correct date values (i.e. 20110103) and without the straight lines that separates the observation?

**UPDATE**

I don't want my values to be plotted on the same vertical line for each day but one after the other. In fact there is 5 minutes time difference between each observations. I decided to convert my `Dates` list using:

```
Dates = [datetime.date(int(d[0:4]), int(d[4:6]), int(d[6:8])) for d in Dates]
```

Then I do:

```
plt.plot(dates, yvalues)
```

and get the following plot:

[image]

Clearly, this picture shows the values on the same date to be on the same vertical lines. I still have the annoying straight lines that separate each dates.

Now if I don't use any dates as for the x-axis, I get the following graph (which is the one that I want but I want the x-axis as dates): [image]

Sample dataset available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nirin5e2owpaszp/data.csv?dl=0)

Comment: So do you want to have lines between each point on each day, but not between each day, and it all to be the same colour? Why not split it into multiple data sets?

Comment: What is the actual data? There might be a better way to visualise it.

Comment: @will I updated the graph that I want in my question but you will see there are no dates on the x-axis otherwise I end-up with the previous (blue bar with space) graphs. I simply want to add dates on my x-axis graph. I don't need any distance between each point but as long as each point on each day does not appear on the same vertical.

Comment: The data structure is exactly like the two list in my question. Thanks for all the help @will

Comment: What actually is the data? This plot you have at the moment is just a mess, do you not think something like a mean with a maximum/minimum envolope, or maybe something like [this](http://ncss.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/ScatterPlot.png).

Comment: The data is a spillover index that varies between -.5 and .5 observed every 5 minutes between 9:30 and 16:00. On the above plot you see one year of data (252 days*77-5 minutes interval). For that index, I didn't store the timestamp for each observation. I only know the order at which the data was drawn in a given day. What I want to see for this graph is the mass of the spillover index that is below 0 (the red line).

Comment: Aha. So idealy, you'd want to have some method to have an envelope which changes time resolution as you zoom in?

Comment: Would you be able to upload a complete data set so i can play around with it?

Comment: @will I added a full year sample dataset in my post (see the last line). Warning, there are some days for which I only have 50 observations. Thanks for your interest in my problem. As for "an envelope which changes time resolution as you zoom in".... I am curious to see that. I will have to report these graph in a paper so I am not sure what is the best way to present it.

Comment: that actually makes it easier, as you can just do multiple plots and won't have to deal with making it interactive. What i mean, is to have it do something like sum up the spillover for some time period, i.e. you don't need 252*77 datapoints on one graph, it's not going to show a huge amount.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64445/discussion-between-will-and-plug4).

Comment: Whats the format of that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after a bit of discussion, here's what i eventually landed on;

```
import datetime
import random
import numpy as np
import datetime
import itertools


dates, allSpillovers, allBins, allDigitised = [], [], [], []
with open("year.dat") as year:
  previousDate = None
  spillovers = []
  for line in year.readlines()[1:]:
    _, strdate, spillover = line.split(",")
    spillover = float(spillover)
    year, month, day = [int(i) for i in strdate.split("-")]

    date = datetime.date(year, month, day)

    if previousDate == date:
      spillovers.append(spillover)
    elif previousDate != None:
      mean = np.mean(spillovers)
      stdev = np.std(spillovers)

      spillovers.sort()
      if len(spillovers) > 70:
          allSpillovers.append([mean, mean-stdev, mean+stdev] + spillovers)
          dates.append(date)
      spillovers = []

    previousDate = date



#itertools.izip_longest(*allSpillovers, fillvalue=0)
allSpillovers = zip(*allSpillovers)


from matplotlib import pyplot

print len(dates), len(allSpillovers[0]), len(allSpillovers[1])

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


for i in range(3, len(allSpillovers)-1):
  alpha = 0.5 - abs(i / float(len(allSpillovers)) - 0.5)
  print len(dates), len(allSpillovers[i]), len(allSpillovers[i+1])
  ax.fill_between(dates, allSpillovers[i], allSpillovers[i+1], facecolor='green', interpolate=True, alpha=alpha, linewidth=0)

#ax.fill_between(dates, allSpillovers[1], allSpillovers[2], facecolor='green', interpolate=True, alpha=0.5)

#for b, d in bins, digitised:



ax.plot(dates, allSpillovers[0], color="blue", linewidth=2)
ax.plot(dates, [0 for _ in dates], color="red", linewidth=2)
ax.grid()

fig.autofmt_xdate()

pyplot.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hehe, you beat me to it!  I was going with using strptime and included fig.autofmt_xdate() as well.

Comment: @will great suggestion. I should have been more clear in my question. I don't want the values for the same date to appear on the same vertical line but one after the other. In fact there is a 5 minute distance between each observations on each day. I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>>> Dates = ['20110103', '20110103', '20110103', '20110108', '20110108', '20110108', '20110113', '20110113', '20110113']
>>> yvalues = [30, 40, -20, 0, -10, 20, 45, 12, -5]
>>> x=range(len(Dates))
>>> plt.xticks(x,Dates)
>>> plt.plot(x,yvalues)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]